# In M theory, what size are the branes/D branes?

Tags: string-theory, branes

In string theory strings are around Planck length, but how big are the D branes in M theory? Can we see them with the LHC?

Comment: There are no actual strings in string theory, therefore they cannot be of any size. Same holds for the branes. They are artificial fields whose action onto some spaces give rise to a particle content in some specified ways.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really true that strings are Planck length.  That's just the typical size of the low energy strings for which string perturbation theory works best.  Strings can be arbitrarily large, in principle.

Similarly, branes can be of arbitrary size.  They can wrap around compact dimensions, or fill all of space.